# How to put text on top some image in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I have an image like this:

[image]

Is there a way to put text on top of this image?

I want some text like this:

[image]

Comment: There is a solution in PSTricks [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57421/19356).

Comment: @Karl'sstudents That's one of the most voted TikZ solutions and you mention PSTricks? :)

Comment: @percusse: I did not realize that fact. :-)